# file() is using cached version

Tags: php, file

When using:

```
file('http://example.com/test.txt');
```

after changing test.txt, i get the chached version for like 5 mins or so. Anyway to disable this caching so that every load it is fresh from the server?

I am attempting to make a way to check for updates of my script.. Here is my code..

```
$configLines = file($url);
foreach ($configLines as $av)
{
    list ($a, $v) = explode("=", $av);
    $$a = $v;
}
```

Comment: I would use curl and set the headers appropriately.

Comment: I suppose this a server`s feature. Read about a 'sendfile' directive, if you have access to domain server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to append some dummy parameter to the URL. This might trick the server into thinking that you are actually requesting a *different* file -

```
file('http://example.com/test.txt?foo='.time());
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks you.. Not sure why I did not think of that sooner!

Comment: @ale - Awesome! Happy to help... I usually use this technique client side to prevent browser caching...